# Parameterized mean not working as expected

Tags: scala

I want to run parameterized mean on a List, however it throws a compile error:

```
def mean[A](xs: Seq[A])(implicit num: Numeric[A]): Option[A] = {
    import num._
    if (xs.isEmpty) None
    else Some(xs.sum / xs.size)
}
```

---

```
cmd11.sc:4: value / is not a member of type parameter A
    else Some(xs.sum / xs.size)
                     ^Compilation Failed
```

What's wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala's numerical hierarchy resembles that of Haskell in a lot of places. In particular, [`Numeric`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric.html) does not support division, since there are plenty of useful types that can be added and multiplied but not divided (matrices being a prime example).

You're looking for [`Fractional`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Fractional.html). You'll also need to convert `xs.size` (which is an `Int`) to your generic type `A`, which can be done with `Fractional.fromInt`.

```
def mean[A](xs: Seq[A])(implicit num: Fractional[A]): Option[A] = {
    import num._
    if (xs.isEmpty) None
    else Some(xs.sum / fromInt(xs.size))
}
```

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Can you maybe provide some short guidance "what use when" when aiming at parameterized numeric ops in Scala?

Comment: The three big players are [`Numeric`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric.html), which supports addition, subtraction, and multiplication; [`Fractional`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Fractional.html), which extends `Numeric` and allows division; and [`Integral`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Integral.html) which also extends `Numeric` and adds support for int division and modulo. Use `Numeric` if all you need is the basic ops, `Fractional` for division, and `Integral` for discrete number theory types of things ("modulo", mainly)

Comment: Can you perhaps answer why `xs.sum`  doesn't need conversion whereas `xs.size` does?

Comment: [`Seq.sum`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html#sum[B%3E:A](implicitnum:scala.math.Numeric[B]):B) takes a collection of numeric things and produces a value of *that same* numeric type. `size` works on any collection (not just numeric ones) and, for the sake of simplicity, always produces a value of type `Int` (since that's what most people would want in casual programming). But you don't want an `Int`; you want an `A`, so we need to do that conversion explicitly.

Comment: Theoretically, they could have made `size` return a polymorphic value, but that would've wrecked type inference, and people would constantly have to write `seq.size[Int]` to get the correct type. So the Scala devs made a judgment call that `Int` is what we really want 90% of the time, so they made that the default.